# Python 2.7 super error

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I created a class in python 2.7. Then I created a subclass of the class that I had created. For defining the **init** of the subclass, I used the super function, but when I ran it on python, it gave an error message:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, l):
       self.p = l
       self.d = len(l)
class C(B):
    def __init__(self, l):
       super(C,self).__init__(l)
```

When I ran C(l) for some variable l, which i had entered, it showed an error message as shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "class_sample.py", line 12, in __init__
super(C,self).__init__(l)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
>>>
```

Comment: Class B needs to inherit from object for new-style classes.

Comment: There are about 900 duplicates of this on SO and elsewhere; learn to Google your error message.

Answer (score 1):

According to python 2.7 [documentation on `super(..)` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

> **Note:** super() only works for [new-style classes](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class).

And your `B` class is an old-style one. So, changing `class B:` to `class B(object)` solves the problem. Here is a slightly edited example:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, l):
       self.p = l
       self.d = len(l)
class C(B):
    def __init__(self, l):
       super(C,self).__init__(l)

c = C([])
print c.d
```

Comment: You're welcome! Note that you can mark reply as an answer to help other visitors and to thank me ;)